# Como centralizar o texto em uma JTextArea ou JTextPane

Tags: java, jtextarea

Nessa imagem o texto não fica centralizado, ele esta muito para cima da `JTextArea`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu também gostaria que o texto começasse no meio da `JTextArea` e fosse se ajustando conforme eu fosse escrevendo.

Qual método posso usar para consertar isso ??

Answer (score 2):

Usando Jpanel você poderia fazer assim:

```
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

Comment: Olá, ele foi pro meio, mas você sabe alguma forma de deixar ele alinhado conforme o tamanho `width` do `JTextPane ` ??